# Mac OS X: GNU parallel can't find the number of cores on a remote server

Tags: macos, bash, parallel-processing, gnu, gnu-parallel

I used homebrew to install GNU parallel on my mac so I can run some tests remotely on my University's servers.  I was quickly running through the [tutorials](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#remote_execution), but when I ran

```
parallel -S <username>@$SERVER1 echo running on ::: <username>@$SERVER1
```

I got the message

```
parallel: Warning: Could not figure out number of cpus on <username@server> (). Using 1.
```

Possibly related, I never added parallel to my path and got the warning that "parallel" wasn't a recognized command, but parallel ran anyways and still echo'd correctly.  This particular server has 16 cores, how can I get parallel to recognize them?

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel is less tested on OS X as I do not have access to an OS X installation, so you have likely found a bug.

GNU Parallel has since 20120322 used these to find the number of CPUs:

```
sysctl -n hw.physicalcpu
sysctl -a hw 2>/dev/null | grep [^a-z]physicalcpu[^a-z] | awk '{ print \$2 }'
```

And the number of cores:

```
sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu
sysctl -a hw  2>/dev/null | grep [^a-z]logicalcpu[^a-z] | awk '{ print \$2 }'
```

Can you test what output you get from those?

Which version of GNU Parallel are you using?

As a work around you can force GNU Parallel to detect 16 cores:

```
parallel -S 16/<username>@$SERVER1 echo running on ::: <username>@$SERVER1
```

Since version 20140422 you have been able to export your path to the remote server:

```
parallel --env PATH -S 16/<username>@$SERVER1 echo running on ::: <username>@$SERVER1
```

That way you just need to add the dir where `parallel` lives on the server to your path on local machine. E.g. `parallel` on the remote server is in `/home/u/user/bin/parallel`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/u/user/bin parallel --env PATH -S <username>@$SERVER1 echo running on ::: <username>@$SERVER1
```

**Information for Ole**

My iMac (OSX MAvericks on Intel core i7) gives the following, which all looks correct:

```
sysctl -n hw.physicalcpu
4


sysctl -a hw
hw.ncpu: 8
hw.byteorder: 1234
hw.memsize: 17179869184
hw.activecpu: 8
hw.physicalcpu: 4
hw.physicalcpu_max: 4
hw.logicalcpu: 8
hw.logicalcpu_max: 8
hw.cputype: 7
hw.cpusubtype: 4
hw.cpu64bit_capable: 1
hw.cpufamily: 1418770316
hw.cacheconfig: 8 2 2 8 0 0 0 0 0 0
hw.cachesize: 17179869184 32768 262144 8388608 0 0 0 0 0 0
hw.pagesize: 4096
hw.busfrequency: 100000000
hw.busfrequency_min: 100000000
hw.busfrequency_max: 100000000
hw.cpufrequency: 3400000000
hw.cpufrequency_min: 3400000000
hw.cpufrequency_max: 3400000000
hw.cachelinesize: 64
hw.l1icachesize: 32768
hw.l1dcachesize: 32768
hw.l2cachesize: 262144
hw.l3cachesize: 8388608
hw.tbfrequency: 1000000000
hw.packages: 1
hw.optional.floatingpoint: 1
hw.optional.mmx: 1
hw.optional.sse: 1
hw.optional.sse2: 1
hw.optional.sse3: 1
hw.optional.supplementalsse3: 1
hw.optional.sse4_1: 1
hw.optional.sse4_2: 1
hw.optional.x86_64: 1
hw.optional.aes: 1
hw.optional.avx1_0: 1
hw.optional.rdrand: 0
hw.optional.f16c: 0
hw.optional.enfstrg: 0
hw.optional.fma: 0
hw.optional.avx2_0: 0
hw.optional.bmi1: 0
hw.optional.bmi2: 0
hw.optional.rtm: 0
hw.optional.hle: 0
hw.cputhreadtype: 1
hw.machine = x86_64
hw.model = iMac12,2
hw.ncpu = 8
hw.byteorder = 1234
hw.physmem = 2147483648
hw.usermem = 521064448
hw.pagesize = 4096
hw.epoch = 0
hw.vectorunit = 1
hw.busfrequency = 100000000
hw.cpufrequency = 3400000000
hw.cachelinesize = 64
hw.l1icachesize = 32768
hw.l1dcachesize = 32768
hw.l2settings = 1
hw.l2cachesize = 262144
hw.l3settings = 1
hw.l3cachesize = 8388608
hw.tbfrequency = 1000000000
hw.memsize = 17179869184
hw.availcpu = 8

sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu
8
```

Comment: @mark-setchell Does GNU Parallel 20140522 detect the correct number of cores/cpus on your machine? If it does, I am not sure what you want me to do with the additional information.

Comment: Yes, it does. I was just trying to help you out with some info that your method looks correct on my Mac.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am still puzzled: How do you see info from a working system will help figuring out what is wrong on non-working systems?

Comment: I was just trying to reassure that your method is still correct in Mavericks. Don't worry.

Comment: @ole Tange I am a little confused here.  Does the remote server also need to have parallel installed on it?

Comment: GNU Parallel uses a remotely installed GNU Parallel to detect the number of CPUs on the remote system. Apart from that GNU Parallel is not needed on the remote system (but then you manually need to specify the number of cores on the remote system).